# Disable a textbox on page load in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a text box and two radio button controls with yes or no value. If I click on `Yes`, the text box should be enable and it should be disabled on `No` selection. I have used ng-disabled property.

But, if user selects `No`, saves the file and reopens it, the text box is getting enabled again. Is there a way to save the text box state?

I have tried using `disabled=""` on `textbox`. but if user selects yes, enters some value and saves the files, the `textbox` is getting disabled again. if user selects `Yes`, the `textbox` should not be disabled till he selects No

I am talking about `index.html` file.

Below is my chunk of code:

```
<input type="radio" name="something" value="1" ng-model="checkboxSelection"/>Checkbox 1
<input type="radio" name="something" value="2" ng-model="checkboxSelection"/> Checkbox 2
<input type="text" ng-model="somevalue" name="somevalue" ng-disabled="checkboxSelection=='2'"/>
```

Comment: Which file are you talking about?

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="disable = !disable">
<input type="text" ng-disabled='disable'/>
```

If you want to clear the value of the input after check no, use a function in you're controller

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="disable_input" ng-value="true" />
<input type="radio" ng-model="disable_input" ng-value="false" />
<input type="text" ng-disabled="disable_input" />
```

I'm not sure if you want to use and `input` or `textarea` as your "textbox" but all you would need to do to make it a `textarea` instead is use the `ng-disabled` in the last `input` element in a `textarea` instead.